# How To Pass EF ObjectContext To Multiple Functions?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a WPF application with a form that updates multiple related tables on one Save button click.  I want to the put the save code into separate functions like shown below.

Will this work?  How can I do this within one ObjectContext and one SaveChanges call?

```
        private void SaveEntity()
        {
            using (var oContext = new MyEntities())
            {
                SaveEntityInfo();
                SaveOwners();
                SavePartners();
                SaveOfficers();
                SaveDirectors();
                oContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: To be clear, do you want the UPDATE statements to all run at the end, or actually run in each individual method? In other words, what do the "Save" function look like?

Comment: pass `oContext` as a parameter to the methods.  What's the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work with some changes. You can change your code this way:

```
private void SaveEntity()
{
    using (var oContext = new MyEntities())
    {
        SaveEntityInfo(oContext);
        SaveOwners(oContext);
        SavePartners(oContext);
        SaveOfficers(oContext);
        SaveDirectors(oContext);
        oContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

//One of multiple save methods
private void SaveEntityInfo(MyEntities context)
{
    //Add something to context
    //Remove something from context
    //Update something in context
    //But never use context.Save() here
    //Let SaveChanges() only calls in your SaveEntity() method
}
```

Comment: This is how I have solved this exact problem in the past.